# Lazily initialize a collection in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In my managed bean I have a code as following :

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map<String, String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
int pageIndex = Integer.valueOf(map.get("page"));
int pageItem = Integer.valueOf(map.get("pageItem"));
int widget = Integer.valueOf(map.get("widget"));

DashboardPageItem dashboardPageItem = new DashboardPageItem();

dashboardPageItem.setPosition(pageItem);
dashboardPageItem.setWidget(widgetService.trouver(widget));

for (DashboardPage dp : dashboard.getPages()) {
    if (dp.getIndex() == pageIndex) {
        dashboardPageItem.setDashboardPage(dp);
        dp.getDashboardPageItems().add(dashboardPageItem);
    }
}
```

but when I run it I get this error message :

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.dashboard.entity.DashboardPage.dashboardPageItems, no session or session was closed
```

So,I have a class called `Dashboard` this class has a list of `DashboardPage`, and each `DashboardPage` has a list of `DashboardPageItem`.

*(Please notice that I always want to fetch all the list of DashboardPageItem when I fetch a DashboardPage entry, and for the DashboardPage list, I don't need to get the list whenever I call a Dashboard entry, just in some cases).*

**I'm using Hibernate without JPA, and this is the hbm for each of the above classes :**

## Dashboard:

```
<class name="Dashboard" table="t_dashboard_das">
    <id name="id" column="das_id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="das_name"/>
    <property name="description" column="das_description"/>
    <property name="visibility" column="das_visibility"/>

    <many-to-one name="createur" 
                 column="fk_sal_id"
                 foreign-key="sal_id"
                 not-null="false"
                 lazy="proxy"/>

    <many-to-one name="role" 
                 column="fk_rol_id"
                 foreign-key="rol_id"
                 not-null="false"
                 lazy="proxy"/>

    <bag table="t_dashboard_page_dpa" name="pages" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all">
        <key column="fk_das_id" not-null="true" unique="false" foreign-key="das_id"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.dashboard.entity.DashboardPage"></one-to-many>    
    </bag>
</class>
```

## DashboardPage:

```
<class name="DashboardPage" table="t_dashboard_page_dpa">
    <id name="id" column="dpa_id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id> 

    <property name="name" column="dpa_name"/>
    <property name="index" column="dpa_index"/>
    <property name="model" column="dpa_model"/>

    <many-to-one name="dashboard" 
                 column="fk_das_id"
                 foreign-key="das_id"
                 not-null="false"
                 lazy="proxy"/>

    <bag table="t_dashboard_page_item_dpi" name="dashboardPageItems" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all">
        <key column="fk_dpa_id" not-null="true" unique="false" foreign-key="dpa_id"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.dashboard.entity.DashboardPageItem"></one-to-many>    
    </bag>             
</class>
```

## DashboardPageItem:

```
<class name="DashboardPageItem" table="t_dashboard_page_item_dpi">
    <id name="id" column="dpi_id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id> 

    <property name="position" column="dpi_position"/>

    <many-to-one name="dashboardPage" 
                 column="fk_dpa_id"
                 foreign-key="dpa_id"
                 not-null="false"
                 lazy="proxy"/>

    <many-to-one name="widget" 
                 column="fk_wid_id"
                 foreign-key="wid_id"
                 not-null="false"
                 lazy="proxy"/>

</class>
```

How can I solve this ?

## Edit :

This is how I retrieve `Dashboard` :

```
this.dashboard = dashboardService.trouver(idDashboard);
```

this will call :

```
 public K get(int id) {
        if(id == 0) return null;
        return  (K) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().get(getClasse(),id);               
    }
```

where `K` is `Dashboard`.

Comment: how do you retrieve dashboard?

Comment: The problem is in how you fetch the 'dashboard' entity, which is exactly the code you're not showing. The non-answer hint without the proper code to look at is 'look into using a fetch join query'.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski please check my edit

Comment: @Gimby plese check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you do not want to send hibernate proxies to your JSF managed bean (pack them into DTO's and work on that).

But regarding your current situation i would suggest creating new service method which would update the dashboard (first it would merge the dashboard to make it managed by the persisten provider):

```
@Transactional
public void updateDashboard(Dashboard dashboard, DashboardPageItem dashboardPageItem){
      Dashboard managedDashboard = session.merge(dashboard);
       for (DashboardPage dp : managedDashboard .getPages()) {
         DashboardPage managedDp = session.merge(dp);
        if (managedDp.getIndex() == pageIndex) {
            dashboardPageItem.setDashboardPage(managedDp);
            managedDp.getDashboardPageItems().add(dashboardPageItem);
        }
       }

       session.merge(managedDashboard);
 }
```

Then from you managed bean you would call:

```
dashboardService.updateDashboard(dashboard, dashobardPageItem)
```

Thanks to that you would be working on your entities always within the transactional context (which i would advise to do in most situations).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this didn't work, I still get the same error message.

Comment: have updated the answer with additional merge on the DashboardPage.. try it out

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is that you want to access a lazy Collection outside of a Transaction.

There are multiple ways to fix this.

1. Access the lazy Collection within a Transaction
2. Fetch the lazy Collection straight in the query

With the 1st approach, you will fix the problem, however there might be performance issues with it.

The preferred way is the second one.

You can read more about this here:
https://arnoldgalovics.com/lazyinitializationexception-demystified/

I'd really suggest reading the whole article because it will clarify lots of things in your head.

Comment: In that example they have gave a solution when you have that exception when initializing a  list for a given object, but what I have is that I don't get the exception in the same level, but when I try to initialize a list of objects in a list of the given object.

Comment: You have the exact same problem in this line: `dp.getDashboardPageItems().add(dashboardPageItem);`

Answer (score -1):

In your Dashboard entity , please make lazy=false. By default , lazy is marked as true by hibernate.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because you are not in transactional context. Maybe you should add @Transactional on your class if you are using spring or cdi. Or @Stateless if you are using ejb

Comment: Which class ? Dashboard ?

Comment: The class which uses dashboard class